# Implicit declaration of function basename in linux

Tags: c, warnings

i am using basename() function in my code.
Where i am including

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

and when i m compiling that code with -Wall flag it shows

following warning

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘basename’
```

if i am writing its declaration in my code

```
char * basename (const char *fname);
```

then it does not show that warning

why this happening.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include `<libgen.h>`.

[The standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/basename.html) says it's in `libgen.h`, [kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/basename.3.html) does so too.

Comment: is it available in standard library.? i mean in each platform will this work..??

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the `man` page for `basename`:

```
man 3 basename
```

You'll see that you need to include `libgen.h` to get the prototype for `basename` (and similar function `dirname`):

```
#include <libgen.h>
```